# How to format a Visualforce inputField

Tags: visualforce, formatting

I want to format the default inputField value on a Visualforce page.  I am pre-filling the number field with 1 but it is displaying as 1.00.

The underlying standard field has a data type of number(10,2).

How can I display the prefilled value as 1 with no decimals?

I consider this not to be a duplicate question because there is not a single right answer and helpful information has been provided here which is different to that provided in similar questions and will be useful to others.

Comment: I have tried using `FLOOR()` function as suggested elsewhere but this results in a syntax error.  It works for outputField but not inputField.  I was unable to provide this information as an edit to the original post as I received an 'error posting edit' with no further information.

Comment: @DanJones, answers are different

Comment: @SantanuBoral - The part of the answer using Java Messaging format is applicable here

Comment: The accepted answer given by @SantanuBoral does exactly what I need, is different to answers given in suggested dulplicates and is the cleanest way of achieving the requirement out of the suggested solitions.  I am unable to add this information as an edit because I receive an error 'unable to save edit' with no explanation as to why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code example to display number format in `InputField`. The `getElementById()` function will take dynamic component based on `id` attribute specified.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountsList}" var="acc" id="accDetail">
    <apex:column headerValue="No. of Locations"> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.NumberofLocations__c}" type="number" id="NumberofLocations">
            <script>                           
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.NumberofLocations}').value = 
                Math.round(document.getElementById('{!$Component.NumberofLocations}').value);
            </script>
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

I have verified that it is working as expected as below picture:

[image: InputField formatting]

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:inputField styleClass="format-num" value="{!Object__c.Field__c}"/>
</apex:form>
<script>
    var val = document.getElementsByClassName('format-num')[0].value;
    document.getElementsByClassName('format-num')[0].value = Math.round(val);
</script>
```